# SmartGit Merge SVN

Tags: git, svn, merge, smartgit

I use SmartGit for a SVN repository und try to resolve a conflict between master and a testbranch. While resolving the conflict in the conflict resolver tool from SmartGit works fine, I cannot push it to the SVN repository.

`svn: E160024: File or directory 'Testdata.txt' is out of date; try updating
 svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating
 svn: E175002: CHECKOUT of '/Repo/!svn/ver/39/Test/Testdata.txt': 409 Conflict (https://...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/svn-tour#merge

Short: Don't merge, do a rebase.